# How to access a key that is in a dictionary within another dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key, emoji

Here I have this code:

```
import emoji

txt = str(input('String: '))

for emoji in emoji.EMOJI_DATA:
    if emoji.EMOJI_DATA['en'] == txt:
        print('The emoji would be here')
```

With that code, I get this error: **Keyerror['en']**, because of course, there is no `'en'` within EMOJI_DATA, so, how could I access what would be the emoji key here?

```
EMOJI_DATA = {
  '': {
      'en' : ':1st_place_medal:',
      'status' : emoji.STATUS["fully_qualified"],
      'E' : 3,
      'de': ':goldmedaille:',
      'es': ':medalla_de_oro:',
      'fr': ':médaille_d’or:',
      'pt': ':medalha_de_ouro:',
      'it': ':medaglia_d’oro:'
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: With the given code and initial dict, this should fail with an AttributeError instead of a KeyError. The `emoji` bound by the loop *has no* attribute `EMOJI_DATA` but it does have the key `'en'`.

Answer (score -1):

Your  code should be like this as you can't access inner key directly.

```
import emoji

txt = str(input('String: '))

for emoji in emoji.EMOJI_DATA:
    if emoji.EMOJI_DATA['']['en'] == txt:
        print('The emoji would be here')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

First of all , you don't need to loop through all items in `emoji.EMOJI_DATA` . You may make use of `lambda` which is more efficient.

```
import emoji

txt = ":1st_place_medal:"

emojiList = emoji.EMOJI_DATA
filteredList = list(filter(lambda x: x[1]["en"] == txt, emojiList.items()))
if(len(filteredList) > 0):
  print("Emoji is ",filteredList[0][0])
  print("Details are ",filteredList[0][1])
else:
  print("Not Found")
```

Comment: Note that `filter` *also* loops through the list and the need for a `lambda` makes it *less* efficient due to the added function call overhead; the need to unpack the result makes is an additional overhead. There is no way that `filteredList` can be `None`; the check is both redundant and incorrect (use `is not None` to avoid operator overload).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi : correct . Is there any lambda function that returns the first item and stop iterating ? something similar to `find` in JavaScript . If so , my approach would be correct , otherwise `filter` loops through the list , yes you are correct .

Comment: A `lambda` is the totally wrong abstraction to affect what `filter` looks at. If anything, you could use `next(filter(…))` to only fetch the first item – `filter` will *still* be looping over the list until the first match, just like a `for` loop but with many more layers involved (three instead of one).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What's your suggestion then , if we don't want to iterate and break when we find the item , any other better method ?

Comment: Any such algorithm *must* iterate and break. Iterate via `for` and `break` is the better method.